# How do I drop a foreign key if it exists in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

There's a function called `index_exists?` in ActionRecord, but no `foreign_key_exists?` on Rails 4.2.7.

So when I call `remove_foreign_key :parties, :franchise_groups` on some databases it breaks.

**What should I use?**

---

**Update**

My code

```
class RemoveForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if foreign_key_exists?(:parties, :franchise_groups)
      remove_foreign_key :parties, :franchise_groups
    end
  end
end
```

gives the error

```
== 20161107163800 RemoveForeignKey: migrating =================================
-- foreign_key_exists?(:parties, :franchise_groups)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `foreign_key_exists?' for #<RemoveForeignKey:0x00000007ea0b58>
/home/rje/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> but no `foreign_key_exists?`

[There is `foreign_key_exists?`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-foreign_key_exists-3F) :)

> Checks to see if a foreign key exists on a table for a given foreign
>   key definition.
>
> ```
> # Checks to see if a foreign key exists.
>   foreign_key_exists?(:accounts, :branches)
> ```
>
> `# Checks to see if a foreign key on a specified column exists. 
>   foreign_key_exists?(:accounts, column: :owner_id)`
>
> `# Checks to see if a foreign key with a custom name exists.
>    foreign_key_exists?(:accounts, name: "special_fk_name")`

Alternatively, you can use [`foreign_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-foreign_keys):

```
if foreign_keys(:table_name).include?(foreign_key_name)
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've given the full error in my question now. Perhaps I'm not understanding the docs.

Comment: can you check inside `up` method if `self.class.included_modules.include?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements)`?

Comment: `puts self.class.included_modules.include?(ActiveRecord::Connectio‌​nAdapters::SchemaSta‌​tements)` just gives me the error `uninitialized constant Connectio‌​nAdapters`. Perhaps this doesn't exist on Rails 4.2?

Comment: @Richard you can use `if foreign_keys(:accounts).include?(foreign_key_name)`

Comment: Available in rails 5.0+ only

Answer (score 7):

On Rails 4 there is no **foreign_key_exists** so I came up with the following solution:

```
remove_foreign_key :events, column: :subscribers_selector_id if foreign_keys(:events).map(&:column).include?("subscribers_selector_id")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use something like this

```
def up
  remove_foreign_key :parties, column: :franchise_groups
end

def down
  add_foreign_key :parties, :franchise_groups
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is checking if the key is there first, not deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

It works on connection:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.foreign_key_exists?(:parties, :franchise_groups)
```

Answer (score 2):

My Rails version doesn't seem to have "foreign_key_exists?" (Rails 4.2.6), so I'm using Array#any? to search through the results from "foreign_keys" and determine whether a given foreign key exists:

```
foreign_keys("parties").any?{|k| k[:to_table] == "franchise_groups"}
```

You can use it as such:

```
if foreign_keys("parties").any?{|k| k[:to_table] == "franchise_groups"}
remove_foreign_key :parties, column: :franchise_group_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Rails 7+ if_exists / if_not_exists options

Rails 7 adds `if_exists` option to `remove_foreign_key` in order to not raise an error when the foreign key is already removed.

Rails 7 adds `if_not_exists` option to `add_foreign_key` in order to not raise an error when the foreign key is already added.

As a result, a migration can be written in the following way:

```rb
class RemoveFranchiseGroupForeignKeysFromParties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_foreign_key :parties, :franchise_groups, if_exists: true
  end

  def down
    add_foreign_key :parties, :franchise_groups, if_not_exists: true
  end
end
```

**Sources:**

- [Add support for if_exists/if_not_exists on remove_foreign_key/add_foreign_key](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42616).
- [remove_foreign_key docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key).
- [add_foreign_key docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key).